# C qsort not sorting last item in multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, qsort

I am using the `qsort` function in C to sort `3` columns of integers. It sorts my 2D array fine, **except for the last item**.

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 10

int array[ARRAYSIZE][3];

static int x_then_z(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *arr1 = (const int*)a;
    const int *arr2 = (const int*)b;
    int diff1 = arr1[0] - arr2[0]; //x
    if(diff1) return diff1;
    return arr1[2] - arr2[2]; //z
}

static int z_then_x(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *arr1 = (const int*)a;
    const int *arr2 = (const int*)b;
    int diff1 = arr1[2] - arr2[2]; //z
    if(diff1) return diff1;
    return arr1[0] - arr2[0]; //x
}

void print_array() {
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    fill_array();
    //print_array();
    //printf("\n");

    qsort(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3*sizeof(int), x_then_z);
    fprintf(stderr, "Sorted by x then z\n");
    print_array();

    printf("\n");

    qsort(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3*sizeof(int), z_then_x);
    fprintf(stderr, "Sorted by z then x\n");
    print_array();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have named my columns `x, y and z` (so as not to confuse myself in the comparison functions where I have `a and b`). The `fill_array` function fills the array with the following computed input:

```
31, 56, 8  
39, 71, 9  
65, 76, 10  
64, 129, 12  
44, 191, 14  
105, 199, 15  
169, 319, 19  
44, 321, 18  
319, 364, 22  
295, 551, 25
```

However, the output is this:

```
Sorted by x then z  
31, 56, 8  
39, 71, 9  
44, 191, 14  
44, 321, 18  
64, 129, 12  
65, 76, 10  
105, 199, 15  
169, 319, 19  
319, 364, 22  
**295, 551, 25**  

Sorted by z then x  
31, 56, 8  
39, 71, 9  
65, 76, 10  
64, 129, 12  
44, 191, 14  
105, 199, 15  
44, 321, 18  
169, 319, 19  
319, 364, 22  
295, 551, 25
```

You can see that the last value of the array is not sorted. If I change `ARRAYSIZE` to a larger number, the last value in the array is not sorted. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try changing `...qsort(array, ARRAYSIZE, 3*...` to `qsort(array, ARRAYSIZE + 1, 3*`.

Comment: The code works fine for me when pasted into https://www.onlinegdb.com/.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger and seeing what is going on inside the `x_then_z` function?

Comment: Can also add prints into the sort functions. perhaps do some pointer arithmetic with array to print the current index. a[2] (1,2,3) > a[6] (4,2,3) may shed some light. However it works for me so suspect code frag is not same as real code.

Comment: I confirm the code posted in the question works, when a `fill_array` function is provided that fills the array with the initial data shown in the question. A reasonable conclusion is that it is likely the code shown in the question is not the same as the code being compiled and executed. There may be some problem in the path to the file being used or the editor not saving the current version of the file. Additionally, when asking questions like this, always include a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `fill_array` source should have been included.

Comment: @Azhy no ? don't do that.

Comment: make sure to do a clean rebuild of the code - you might just be running an old version with a bug.

Comment: As most of you probably surmise, `fill_array` is very large and complicated, and calls a lot of other functions. So I have left it out for brevity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fill_array` function had an off by 1 error. When filling the array, it was starting at 1, not 0